# I have a MongoDB database and I want only a specific user accessing his private data

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB database, express and angular in the frontend.
I already have AUTH setup in a collection and another collection for storing Data.

Right now users can log in and save data, but the data that they save right now is global, meaning I could come and add 1) Learn MongoDB and the second user when they sign in sees the same thing. 
 I want users to be able to only see the data that he/she posts.

I have been browsing the internet for this specific tutorial but haven't found anything.

If someone could point me in the right direction and a little introduction on it, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

At its core, this is very very simple. Say, you have a todo list application. So it has Users and Tasks. So the index page for Tasks has this code now (pseudocode ahead):

```
tasks = db.tasks.find()
render tasks
```

Naturally, all users see all tasks. What you need to change is now pass  id of the logged-in user to the query:

```
tasks = db.tasks.find({user_id: current_user.id})
render tasks
```

That's it, now all users see only their own tasks. Do this for all other kinds of private data.